# Get multiple checked box value in array format using angular 4

Tags: angular

**Component.html**

```
  <div class="tab-content">
     <div class=" fl-wrap filter-tags" *ngIf="selected">
         <label *ngFor="let category of selected.categoryServicemodel; let i = index">
            <input type="checkbox" (click)="onCheck(category)"
                class="form-control" value="!!category.isActive"
                (ngModelChange)="category.isActive = $event ? 1 : 0"
                name="index{{i}}"
            >
            {{category.serviceName}}
         </label>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**This is my component.ts**

```
export class Component {
 selectedServe: [];

   constructor(){
    this.service.getAllCategories()
       .subscribe((categories:any )=>{           
         this.values = categories.json();
         console.log(this.values);
       })

  this.service.getAllServices()
      .subscribe((services:any )=>{
        this.serv = services.json();
        console.log(this.serv)
      })
    }

 onCheck(service){
  this.selectedServe = service.serviceId;
  console.log(this.selectedServe);
 }
```

[image: checkbox]

Now i have multiple checkbox when i select checkbox each value id should be stored in a array format variable

Comment: What sets `this.selected`?  What data type is `this.selected`?  This information is not shown.

Comment: The checkboxes currently don't have a “value ID.”  Where does the value for a checked box come from?

Comment: that is to check the selected checkbox values

Comment: It will easy using reactive form model instead of template-driven model

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes as shown in the template don't get a “value ID,” so here's a solution that gets an array of checked names.  Adjust as needed.

```
get checkedServiceNames() {
    return this.selected.categoryServicemodel
        .filter(category => !!category.isActive)
        .map(category => category.serviceName);
}
```

Test by putting this in your template:

```
{{ checkedServiceNames | json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample example : 
Take 1 array variable in component and bind checkbox with that component.

```js
elm=[true, false, false, true];

go(){
    console.log(this.elm); // For verification
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  (change)="go()" [(ngModel)]="elm[0]">1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="elm[1]">2 <br>
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="elm[2]">3 <br>
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="elm[3]">4
```